# Magento 2:Show category name in cart page

Tags: magento2, category, shopping-cart, name

I have a custom module. I want to display category name of each product in the cart

Please see my code

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="additional.product.info">
        <block class="Company\Module\Block\Showcategory" name="showcategory" template="Company_Module::checkout/cart/categoryname.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

categoryname.phtml

```
<?php $quoteItems = $block->getCheckoutSession(); ?>
<?php echo count($quoteItems); ?>
<?php foreach ($quoteItems as $item): 
    $pid = $item->getProductId();
    $product = $block->getProductRepository()->getById($pid);
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
        $_cat = $block->getCategoryRepository()->get($category_id, $block->getStoreId());
        echo $_cat->getName();
    }
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Showcategory.php

```
<?php 

namespace Company\Module\Block;  

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Showcategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /** @var ProductRepository */
    private $productRepository;

    /** @var CategoryRepository */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /** @var StoreManager */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
     * @param StoreManager $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function getCheckoutSession() {
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        return $items;
    }

    public function getProductRepository() {
        $product = $this->productRepository;
        return $product;
    }

    public function getCategoryRepository() {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository;
        return $category;
    }

    public function getStoreId() {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        return $storeId;
    }    
}
```

But it is showing all category names under each product. Please refer the image
[image]

Please advice

Comment: I guess that you want show the category name from where you have do addtocart?

Comment: I want to show the category name of the product for each product in the cart page.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use categoryCollection instead of loading each category with a particular database query. This will result into a better performance when loading the cart page.  Also, if `$item` is instance of quoteItem, you don't have to load the product again because you can find it inside quoteItem object. So, check the following code.

```
<?php $item = $block->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
$cats = $block->getCategoryCollectionFactory()->create();
$cats->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $product->getCategoryIds());

foreach ($cats as $category) {
    echo $category->getName();
} ?>
```

`getCategoryCollectionFactory()` should return an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory`

Also, i would suggest you to move the whole code inside your block and in phtml just call a method to take an array with category names.

Comment: What is function getItem(). Can you please add the code for function getItem()

Comment: You don't need to implement getItem() method as long as your block is child of `additional.product.info` block because, as you can see in it's template (`module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/additional/info.phtml`), magento 2 set quote item on each child block.

Comment: Solution won't work. $block->getCategoryCollectionFactory() would be null in this case.

Answer (score 1):

checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="additional.product.info">
        <block class="Gaurav\Companyname\Block\Showcategory" name="showcategory" template="Gaurav_Companyname::categoryname.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Gaurav\Companyname\Block\Showcategory.php

```
<?php 
namespace Gaurav\Companyname\Block;  
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Showcategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /** @var ProductRepository */
    private $productRepository;

    /** @var CategoryRepository */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /** @var StoreManager */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
     * @param StoreManager $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        //die('gaurav');
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    public function getProductRepository() {
        $product = $this->productRepository;
        return $product;
    }

    public function getCategoryRepository() {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository;
        return $category;
    }
    public function getStoreId() {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        return $storeId;
    }  

  public function getCategoryName(){
    $item = $this->getItem(); 
    $pid = $item->getProductId();
    $product = $this->getProductRepository()->getById($pid);
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $cat_name = array();
    foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
        $_cat = $this->getCategoryRepository()->get($category_id, $this->getStoreId());
        $cat_name[] = $_cat->getName();

    }
    return $cat_name;
  }

}
```

Gaurav\Companyname\view\frontend\templates\categoryname.phtml

```
<?php 
$category_names = $block->getCategoryName();
foreach($category_names as $cat_name){
    echo $cat_name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $item = $block->getItem(); 
$pid = $item->getProductId();
$product = $block->getProductRepository()->getById($pid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = $block->getCategoryRepository()->get($category_id, $block->getStoreId());
    echo $_cat->getName();

} ?>
```

please check above code